# Value not assign to label present on layout page from angularjs controller MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am assigning user name to label upon login successfull, but it is not assigned.

Below is my html

```
<body class="nav navbar-nav" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AccountsController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <label for="User_Name" style="color:red;">{{User_Name}}</label>
      </div>  
</body>
```

Below is my AngularJs controller

```
var AccountsController = function ($scope, $http, $location,UserService) {
    $scope.User_Name = "";
    $scope.Login_Click = function (UserName, Password) {
        $http.get('/api/AppAccounts/GetAuthenticateUser', { params: { UserName: UserName, Password: Password } }).
          success(function (data) {
              if (data.length > 0) {
                  UserService.isLogged = true; //Angularjs Service
                  UserService.username = data[0].UserName;
                  $scope.User_Name = data[0].UserName;
                  $location.path('/Three');
              }
              else {
                  UserService.isLogged = false;
                  UserService.username = "";
              }
          }).
          error(function (error) {
              UserService.isLogged = false;
              UserService.username = "";
          });
    }
};
```

I have my angular app code in another file and its working fine with rest of the pages but whenever I try to assign value to label that is present on layout page, it dont get assigned. What I,m doing wrong here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When MVC renders your view, It render your page and layout as one page. Your angular/client side javascript code is going to be executed on the rendered HTML. You should be able to display the value of a scope property anywhere in your page as long as it is inside an element which has `ng-app` and `ng-controller` set to it properly. I tried this and it worked fine.

Try these to troubleshoot the issue.

**Make sure that your ajax call works and the success handler is executed.**

Since you are setting the value to User_Name property in the success handler, you need to make sure that, the success handler is being executed. You can check it by simply putting an `alert/console.log` in different parts of your code.

```
$scope.Login_Click = function (UserName, Password) {
    $http.get('/api/AppAccounts/GetAuthenticateUser', 
                                 { params: { UserName: UserName, Password: Password } }).
      success(function (data) {
          alert('success');
          console.log(data);
          if (data.length > 0) {
              UserService.isLogged = true; //Angularjs Service
              UserService.username = data[0].UserName;
              $scope.User_Name = data[0].UserName;
              $location.path('/Three');
          }
          else {
              alert('data length is zero');
              UserService.isLogged = false;
              UserService.username = "";
          }
      }).
      error(function (error) {
          alert('ajax failed');
          console.log(error);
          UserService.isLogged = false;
          UserService.username = "";
      });
}
```

**Make sure that you are returning an array from your api method.**

In the success handler, you are reading the UserName property of the first item in the response. That means, the response should be an array. Make sure it is a JSON array which looks like this.(You can open your browser's developer tools-> Network tab and see the result of your ajax call.

```
[
  {
    "UserName": "Test"
  }
]
```

If you are sending back a single object like  `{ UserName : "Tes"}` from your web api method, you should access it like

```
success(function(data){
   $scope.User_Name = data.UserName;
})
```

**Make sure that you are using the correct http method to send data from client.**

In your code, you are using `$http.get` method. that means it is going to send an Http GET method to the endpoint/url you provided. Make sure that your web api end point responds properly for a GET method. You can test this by accessing the url directly in a browser and adding UserName and Password in querystring

```
yoursite.com/api/AppAccounts/GetAuthenticatedUser?UserName=some&Password=test
```

it is not a good idea to keep your GetAuthenticated user method as a GET method. I recommend changing it to `HttpPost`  type and use `$http.post` from your client code.

**Other script errors in the page.**
If you have other script errors in the page, you will have trouble executing the remaining javascript. Open up your browser console and check for other script errors and fix those if you see any.

Finally, I suggest you to use the `done` and `fail` method on the promise returned by $.post/$.get methods.

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
>   the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information). The jqXHR.done() (for success),
>   jqXHR.fail() (for error), and jqXHR.always() (for completion, whether
>   success or error) methods take a function argument that is called when the 
>   request terminates

```
$.post( "yoururl", function(res) {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function(res) {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
```